# Popover closes when mouse clicks on NSTextField autosuggestion

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield, nspopover

I have a NSViewController that is shown as a popover with the method:

`presentViewController(_ viewController: NSViewController, asPopoverRelativeTo positioningRect: NSRect, of positioningView: NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge, behavior: NSPopover.Behavior)`

The behavior is set to transient. In the popover, I have a NSTextField subclass with autocomplete suggestions enabled by providing an array of Strings using the method:

```
optional func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, completions words: [String], forPartialWordRange charRange: NSRange, indexOfSelectedItem index: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) -> [String]
```

in the delegate of the NSTextField subclass. Autocompletion and suggestions works fine so far. However, whenever the users click on an suggested string, the popover disappears. However the popover does not disappear when the users select a suggested item via cursors and tab. The list of suggestions is inside the popover, i.e. the view rectangle of the suggestions does not protrude outside the view rectangle of the popover.

My question: what can I do to prevent the popover from closing in this situation?